# SharePoint 2013 certification 70-331 preparation

Tags: document, certification

Currently I'm working on SharePoint 2013 as a developer. Please suggest me, where to get documents/reading material to crack 70-331 certification.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  certification question dumps, not SharePoint. These questions are property of Microsoft and not meant to be distributed

Comment: You're looking for help cheating on your exam?

Comment: I'll mark it for deletion but Certification tag is already present in stackexchange and same is tagged here.

Comment: Please review a similar question at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10897/are-sharepoint-certifications-worthwhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just gonna give you some tips that helped me when studying for exams.

I would suggest [watching this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2_v7E2jjdE). It covers some, if you are insecure in how the exams are, and gives you an idea of what's coming on the exam.

General tip is to look for study guides ([Like this one](http://www.savtechsol.com/Education/Exam-Prep/Pages/Exam-70-331-Study-Guide.aspx)), just an example don't really know if it's good enough. Microsoft [provides a list](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-za/exam-70-331.aspx) of what's coming on the exam.

The list is very "General". But from that you can fairly easily find various Technet and MSDN articles that covers the particular subjects.

Go to http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ for coverage on basic SharePoint learning videos.